# sql query get all data from Jan to current month even if there are no records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not good with sql so any help world be great

I have a SQL query that gets records who has register from Jan to current month

My code example

```
SELECT DatePart(YEAR, p.createStamp) as TheYear, DatePart(MONTH, p.createStamp) as TheMonth ,  COUNT(p.pId) AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM profile p with(nolock)
where DatePart(YEAR, p.createStamp) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(p.createStamp), MONTH(p.createStamp)
ORDER BY YEAR(p.createStamp), MONTH(p.createStamp)
```

how ever the query will bring back

February = 2, March = 3, April = 4 and May = 5

i would like to have it bring back Jan = 1 with a total count of 0 and June = 6 with the total count of 0 as well any ideas how to do this?

thank you.

Comment: sql server version please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a loop to create the month/year combinations and use this as the base of your query:

```
declare @startDate as datetime
set @startDate = '1/1/13'

declare @currentDate as datetime
set @currentDate = '6/6/13'

select
     month(@currentDate) as monthOfDate
    ,year(@currentDate) as yearOfDate
into #allDates
where 1=0

while (@startDate <= @currentDate)
begin
    insert into #allDates values (month(@startDate),year(@startDate))
    set @startDate = dateadd(m,1,@startDate)
end

select 
     _monthYear.yearofDate
    ,_monthYear.monthOfDate
    , COUNT(p.pId) as total
from #allDates _monthYear
left join profile p with(nolock)
    on month(p.createStamp) = _monthYear.monthOfDate
    and year(p.createStamp) = _monthYear.yearOfDate
group by
     _monthYear.yearofDate
    ,_monthYear.montOfDate

drop table #allDates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select what's not there, so I suggest making a lookup table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Months (Year_ INT, Month_ INT)
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=20)
BEGIN
--Do Stuff
INSERT INTO #Months
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,@intflag,'20121201')),MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,@intflag,'20121201'))
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

You can change the '20' to be any number of months you want, and change '20121201' in both spots to the month before the month you want to start your lookup.

Then Joining to that table, I believe the following will work:

```
SELECT m.Year_ as TheYear, m.Month_ as TheMonth ,  ISNULL(COUNT(p.pId),0) AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM profile p
RIGHT JOIN #Months m
ON DatePart(YEAR, p.createStamp) = m.Year_
AND  DatePart(MONTH, p.createStamp) = m.Month_
where DatePart(YEAR, p.createStamp) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
GROUP BY m.Year_, m.Month_
ORDER BY  m.Year_, m.Month_
```

Comment: It's possible to simulate the table Months without actually having to create it within a db. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754598/mysql-show-all-dates-between-even-if-no-result for simulating days.

Comment: Anyone know offhand if the ISNULL is needed on the COUNT? Can't recall offhand.

Comment: @meewoK good call, could probably use a CTE too, I end up using calendar tables for a number of analyses, so like them to be permanent.