# How to echo whole week statistics from mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, if-statement

i have been thinking and i cant solve this by myself.

i have this mysql table with the statistics of a website visitors

```
+-----------------------------+
+ date        | visits        +
+-----------------------------+
+  2014-03-02 | 736           +
+  2014-03-03 | 936           +
+  2014-03-06 | 54            +                 
+-----------------------------+
```

And i want to echo a week stats report but also showing the days in which the table has no data.

The output should be:

```
2014-03-01: 0
2014-03-02: 736
2014-03-03: 936
2014-03-04: 0
2014-03-05: 0
2014-03-06: 54
2014-03-07: 0
```

Please note i know how to do this with this function:

```
$first = '2014-03-01';

$last = '2014-03-07';

while (strtotime($first) <= strtotime($last)) {

$related10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE date >= '$first' and date <= '$last'");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($related10);
$date = $rows['date'];
$visits = $rows['visits'];

echo ''.$date.': '.$visits.'';

$first = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($first)));
}
```

But the problem of this function is that it runs one sql query for each date, and for large date ranges it lasts minutes in loading the page.

I would like to get this done with one sql query

It should be something like this

```
$related10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE fecha >= '$first' and fecha <= '$last'");

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($related10)) {

//function to add the missing date data.
echo $output;

}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754598/mysql-show-all-dates-between-even-if-no-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rafal beat me to it, put here is the general idea. Note that I'm running two loops here but you could probably improve upon the algorithm further.

```
// first put the date value into the "key" of each array item
$rows2 = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $rows2[$row['date']] = $row['visits'];
}


$currentTs = strtotime('2014-03-01');
$lastTs = strtotime('2014-03-07');

while ($currentTs < $lastTs) {
    $displayDate = date('Y-m-d', $currentTs);
    echo $displayDate . " = ";
    if (!empty($rows2[$displayDate])) {
        echo $rows2[$displayDate]; // echo the visits
    }
    else {
        echo '0';
    }

    echo "\n";
    $currentTs = strtotime('+1 day', $currentTs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right with the performance!

You could fetch all records once and keep them in an array, where date would be the key. Then, in your loop, you could check if that date exists in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to create a small utility table, you could use [this solution (SQLFiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02fbd/24).

```
CREATE TABLE ints ( i tinyint );

INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Then in PHP

```
$related10 = mysql_query("
SELECT calendar.date,
       ifnull(stats.visits, 0) AS visits
  FROM (SELECT DATE('$first') + INTERVAL a.i*100 + b.i*10 + c.i DAY AS date
      FROM ints a
      JOIN ints b
      JOIN ints c
     WHERE (a.i*100 + b.i*10 + c.i) <= DATEDIFF('$last', '$first')
        ) calendar
   LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.date = calendar.date
  ORDER BY calendar.date
");
```

If you need to handle differences of more than 1000 days, just keep adding joins to the `ints` table and multiplications by powers of 10 until you can cover the days you need. Credit to Brian Showalter at http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables for the idea to `SELECT` calendar data.