# SQL : Query Show date range with if

Tags: mysql

I have a problem about syntax in MySQL... let me show to you

**Expected Result**

|  ID | Date            | Status |
|-----|----------------|----------| 
|  2  | 2014-06-10  | H         | 
|  2  | 2014-06-11  | O         | 
|  2  | 2014-06-12  | H         | 
**|  2  | 2014-06-13  | -          |** 

|  2  | 2014-06-14  | H         |

**Problem**
in my database Date = **2014-06-13** not found but I want still show with status  **' - '** .

**Query have tried**

```
SELECT id,date,status 
FROM v_absensi 
WHERE site_absensi='IDJK068PBP' 
  AND tanggal != 'Belum Ada' 
  AND DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( tanggal ,'%d/%m/%Y' ) ,'%Y/%m/%d' )
      BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '18/06/2014' ,'%d/%m/%Y' ) ,'%Y/%m/%d' )
      AND DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '23/06/2014' ,'%d/%m/%Y' ) ,'%Y/%m/%d' ) 
  AND id='2'
```

Need your Advice Guys 
Thanks for your advice !!!

Comment: Already asked several times: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754598/mysql-show-all-dates-between-even-if-no-result) may help you.

Comment: @tailorBird : thanks.. I will go to your link

Comment: Have other examples to me again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dummy table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE aDummyTable ( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, PRIMARY KEY (id) );
```

Then insert some values:

```
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO aDummyTable (id) VALUES (NULL);
```

Consider this as your table:

```
CREATE TABLE  urTable (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  dateVal date,
  val varchar(10),
   PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

Insert some values for example :

```
INSERT INTO urTable  (id,dateVal,val)VALUES   (1,'2014-06-10','H');
INSERT INTO urTable  (id,dateVal,val)VALUES   (2,'2014-06-11','O');
INSERT INTO urTable  (id,dateVal,val)VALUES   (3,'2014-06-12','H');
INSERT INTO urTable  (id,dateVal,val)VALUES   (4,'2014-06-14','H');
```

Here is your result.

```
SELECT x.ts AS time,
         COALESCE(y.val, '-') AS urVal
     FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2014-06-10', INTERVAL n.id - 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') AS ts
             FROM aDummyTable n
            WHERE DATE_ADD('2014-06-10', INTERVAL n.id - 1 DAY) <= '2014-06-14') x
LEFT JOIN urTable y  ON  DATE_FORMAT(dateVal, '%Y-%m-%d') = x.ts;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0465d/2)

Comment: sorry for the late response... thants work guys.. thanks alot