# Mysql- How to check particular query returns no result

Tags: mysql

I have the user transaction table. Need a consolidated report from it based on date wise.The query can be like

```
select sum(a),count(b),c from u_txn where Date(date) between('2014-12-01') 
and ('2014-12-25') group by Date(date);
```

The difficulty is if the transaction not happening in any one of the date, can i get my column values as 0. Is it possible without for-loop and stored procedure?. 
improved formatting

Comment: Create a dates table, insert all dates you want, then use dates table left join transaction table.

Comment: Without the date table it couldn't be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dynamically build a date table [such as in another post I clarified in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754598/mysql-show-all-dates-between-even-if-no-result/13754729#13754729).  However, just included here for your query implementation.  I just used your "u_txn" table as the basis of getting records for 25 days (clarified in other answer).  Since the inner query is generating dates Dec 1 to Dec 25, you dont need the extra where clause for the date range as it is working based on the left-join to the transaction detail table.

```
select
      AllDaysYouWant.MyJoinDate,
      sum(T.a),
      count(T.b),
      c 
   from 
      ( select
              @curDate := Date_Add(@curDate, interval 1 day) as MyJoinDate
           from
              ( select @curDate := '2014-12-01' ) sqlvars,
              u_txn
           limit 25 ) AllDaysYouWant
      LEFT JOIN u_txn T
         on AllDaysYouWant.MyJoinDate = Date( T.Date )
   group by
      AllDaysYouWant.MyJoinDate
```