# How to generate the week to week dates based on given number of years

Tags: php, mysql, date

Here i am trying to start date and end date values to database.

here i am calling this create sharing dates function to add values to database.
when i call this function
the function 1st gets the `$sharing` value. the `$sharing` value will be  '`1 week`' or '`2 week`' or '`3 week`'...

`$from_date` will have a date value in it.
`$product_life` will have the value like `1 year` or `2 year`...

i want to add the values to database in an iteration.. Say.

i have a `$product_life = 1 year`,i have a `from_date = 2016-02-23`, and `sharing_basis= 1 week`

when i call the `createSharingdates($productId)` with above values, it will fetch the users for that product by `order_datetime` and then add sharing date for each user.but here i am able to generate the sharing dates only for 1 cycle.

For.ex if there are 4 users i am able to generate dates for 4 users only once.
like

```
user_id: 1
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-02-02  
end_date: 2015-02-09

user_id: 2
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-02-10  
end_date: 2015-02-17

user_id: 3
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-02-18  
end_date: 2015-03-26

user_id: 4
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-02-27  
end_date: 2015-03-05
```

what i want to do is i want to generate sharing dates untill `product_life` ends

**ex:**
if product life has `product_life` as one year i want to generate the dates for that 1 year on the sharing_basis. so that the out put will be like..

Output:

```
user_id: 1
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-02-02  
end_date: 2015-02-09

user_id: 2
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-02-10  
end_date: 2015-02-17

user_id: 3
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-02-18  
end_date: 2015-02-26

user_id: 4
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-02-27  
end_date: 2015-03-05


user_id: 1
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-03-06  
end_date: 2015-03-13

user_id: 2
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-03-14  
end_date: 2015-03-21

user_id: 3
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-03-28  
end_date: 2015-03-35

user_id: 4
product_id: 24
start_date: 2015-03-42  
end_date: 2015-03-49
... continues
```

Code:

```
function createSharingdates($productId){
    $sharing_basis = getSharingBasis($productId); 
    $product_life = getlife($productId); 
    $from_date = getStartdate($productId);
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM orders WHERE product_id='$productId' ORDER BY order_datetime";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                                
        $product_id = $productId;       
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {              
            $user_id = $row["user_id"];
            $to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$sharing_basis, strtotime($from_date)));         
            addSharingDates($product_id,$user_id,$from_date,$to_date);
            $from_date = $to_date;
    }
    $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a loop over the available weeks (from `$from_date` to `$product_life`), in each turn take the next user (which you may want to put into an array so you can easily go from one to the next and back to the start when the end is reached). The PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Class will then help you to get the start and end date.

Answer (score 0):

[Starting with a similar link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754598/mysql-show-all-dates-between-even-if-no-result/13754729#13754729) the user wanted all possible dates within a given range, but did not have a fixed table of dates.  You can dynamically generate a table within your query, then use that as a basis for the rest of your query / users...  For example, getting 52 weeks starting with 2015-02-02...  You could obviously change whatever the start date was, and limit the end based on how many LIMIT records (26 weeks, 52 weeks, 104 weeks, etc) as needed.

```
select
      @curDate := Date_Add(@curDate, interval 1 day) as WeekStart,
      Date_Add( @curDate, interval 7 day ) as WeekEnd
   from
      ( select @curDate := '2015-02-02' ) sqlvars,
      AnyOtherTable
   limit 52 ) AllWeeksYouNeed
```

Now, you want to get transactions of all users who purchased a given product, just join the two results.

```
SELECT 
      o.user_id,
      o.Product_ID,
      AllWeeksYouNeed.WeekStart,
      AllWeeksYouNeed.WeekEnd
   FROM 
      orders o
         JOIN ( above entire query ) AllWeeksYouNeed
   WHERE 
      o.product_id='$productId' 
   ORDER BY 
      o.order_datetime
```

This WOULD Create a Cartesian result, which I do NOT think is what you want... but it would give you one record per person, per week based on the duration you can adjust for (1yr, 2yr, whatever).

Now, the SHARING component is a little odd...  This could be done based on a rotation assignment in the first query.  However, I do not want to confuse that to you without understanding a little more the PURPOSE of "Sharing".  it almost looks like a rotation queue of some kind.